# Can UTF-8 string contain NULLs (0x0) in it?

Tags: unicode, utf-8

If so, is it allowed anywhere in the string?

Comment: In what language? In C, the null character (not `NULL`, that's a null pointer constant) marks the end of a string. Other languages might permit strings to contain null characters other than at the end.

Comment: Strings don't have "terminators". A terminator is a part of some specific *representation* of a string; "array of bytes, one byte per string character, followed by a null byte". There are other representations of strings that don't use terminators.

Comment: On a pedantic note regarding your question title: "Contain" already means "in it"...

Comment: @KeithThompson without any language in consideration, just by how UTF-8 encoding is defined in RFC. UTF-8 encoding doesn't depend on a programming language. If a language supports something UTF-8-like but diverges from the UTF-8 standard, then it's a "modified UTF-8". I'm talking about an unmodified one, one that doesn't depend on any particular implementation.

Comment: UTF-8 is indifferent on the matter.

Comment: Removed "null terminator" example from the question, as it confused some of you. I'm just asking if a valid UTF-8 string can contain 0x0 anywhere in it.

Comment: 0x0 is a valid code in UTF-8.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it could easily be resolved through trial and error.

Comment: @DavidZemens trial and error of what exactly?

Comment: Java, for example, supports only Modified UTF-8 https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8#Modified_UTF-8 in which 0x0 is replaced with something, so you can't really resolve it through trial and error unless you know exactly what UTF-8 encoding is supported by the thing you do trial and error on, and many implementations don't specify that, so if an implementation of UTF-8 encoder/decoder doesn't support 0x0 it doesn't say anything about whether it's supported in UTF-8, since the implementation could have bent UTF-8 for its needs, making it a Modified UTF-8, when I care about a non-modified UTF-8.

Comment: @YellowRay: Do you mean [RFC 3629](https://tools.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3629.txt)?

Comment: @KeithThompson the most recent one (not sure if it's RFC 3629)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, UTF-8 defines 0x0 as `NUL`. There is no reason that cannot be part of a UTF-8 stream. RFC 3629 specifically covers this case:

> Character numbers from U+0000 to U+007F (US-ASCII repertoire)
>         correspond to octets 00 to 7F (7 bit US-ASCII values).  A direct
>         consequence is that a plain ASCII string is also a valid UTF-8
>         string.

As you're aware, there are various storage formats that have trouble encoding `NUL`, and so there is modified UTF-8 which gives an alternate encoding, but "unmodified" UTF-8 requires it to be encoded as 0x0 (encoding it as C0 80 is explicitly called out in section 10 as illegal UTF-8).

Comment: This answer is misleading. No, NUL cannot be in any arbitrary place in a UTF-8 string, the extension bytes may not be NUL. And it may happen in a stream, or a buffer, but not in a c string. C strings are NUL terminated, whether utf-8 or not.

Comment: @ArashKazemi. No one mentioned C, so I don't see why it's relevant. I don't see anything misleading about this answer.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'd be interested if rephrasing the question as follows would give a different answer: Can a null byte be included in a valid UTF-8 string, other than as a null terminator such as that found in a C string (or if you somehow have intermediary null terminators for some reason). Or put another way, would `\0` ever be valid in a mutli-byte character's representation?

Comment: @DrewNoakes 0x00 is always the one-byte NUL **character** in UTF-8. It cannot be part of a multi-byte character's representation (by design, no one-byte UTF-8 sequences are ever ambiguous). It does not have to be "a null terminator." That's a semantic interpretation that UTF-8 does not impose. The rules for C-string termination are not relevant to what UTF-8 bytes encode. The hex sequence "61 00 61" ("a NUL a") is a perfectly valid UTF-8 sequence (also a perfectly valid ASCII sequence). That many C-like parsers will choose to truncate it doesn't make it invalid UTF-8.

Comment: For an example of a common use-case of embedded NUL in ASCII (long-predating UTF-8, but equivalent in UTF-8), see the pairing of `find ... -print0` and `xargs -0 ...`. This separates records with \0 rather than \n, and is extremely useful.